# Using \subfigure in the sciposter document class

Tags: subfloats, sciposter

I'm creating a poster and would like to include subfigures, just to group everything together.  However, I'm having problems.  I pasted code that worked in an article class document and it is now giving me an error.

I realize that there is \figure and \subfigure encoded into the sciposter class.  But I can't seem to figure out how to make it work!

Here's what I'm trying:

```
\documentclass[landscape, ra0,plainboxedsections]{sciposter}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure} 
    \centering

    \begin{subfigure}[a]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
        \tikzset{dot/.style={circle,fill=#1,inner sep=0,minimum size=4pt}}
        \draw (1,3) node[dot=black]{}--(2,5)node[dot=black]{}--(3,2)node[dot=black]{}--     (4,1)node[dot=black]{}--(5,4)node[dot=black]{};
        \draw (1.5,4) node[xshift=-.3cm] {\small $X_1$};
        \draw(2.5,3.25) node[xshift=-.2cm] {\small $X_2$};
        \draw(3.5,1.25) node[xshift=-.2cm] {\small $X_3$};
        \draw(4.5,2.5) node[xshift=.3cm] {\small $X_4$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{$\pi=35214$}
    \end{subfigure}

\hspace{0.1\textwidth}

    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
        \tikzset{dot/.style={circle,fill=#1,inner sep=0,minimum size=4pt}}
        \draw (1,2) node[dot=black]{}--(2,5)node[dot=black]{}--(3,4)node[dot=black]{}-- (4,1)node[dot=black]{}--(5,3)node[dot=black]{};
        \draw (1.5,3.5) node[xshift=-.3cm] {\small $X_4$};
        \draw(2.5,4.5) node[xshift=.2cm,yshift=.2cm] {\small $X_3$};
        \draw(3.5,2.5) node[xshift=-.2cm, yshift=-.1cm] {\small $X_2$};
        \draw(4.5,2) node[xshift=.3cm] {\small $X_1$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{$\pi^{RC}=25413$}
    \end{subfigure}

\caption{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please add all packages you need to compile your example above.

Comment: tike added.  There is some xcolor error I get, but it doesn't seem to be fatal, and the \subfigure error still shows, so hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the `subfigure` syntax defined by the `subcaption` package<sup>1</sup>, and this is completely different to that defined in `sciposter.cls`. That definition, from lines 797-805 of `sciposter.cls`, is

```
\newcommand{\subfigure}[2][]{
\refstepcounter{subfig}
\begin{tabular}{c}
 #2 \\
 (
 \alph{subfig}
 ) #1\\
\end{tabular}
}
```

meaning that `\subfigure` is a command with two arguments. The first one is the caption text, and is optional, the second is the image itself:

```
\subfigure[<optional caption text>]{<image/tikzpicture>]
```

A working version of your code is therefore

```
\documentclass[landscape, ra0,plainboxedsections]{sciposter}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure} 
    \centering

\subfigure[$\pi=35214$]{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
        \tikzset{dot/.style={circle,fill=#1,inner sep=0,minimum size=4pt}}
        \draw (1,3) node[dot=black]{}--(2,5)node[dot=black]{}--(3,2)node[dot=black]{}--     (4,1)node[dot=black]{}--(5,4)node[dot=black]{};
        \draw (1.5,4) node[xshift=-.3cm] {\small $X_1$};
        \draw(2.5,3.25) node[xshift=-.2cm] {\small $X_2$};
        \draw(3.5,1.25) node[xshift=-.2cm] {\small $X_3$};
        \draw(4.5,2.5) node[xshift=.3cm] {\small $X_4$};
        \end{tikzpicture}}  
\hspace{0.1\textwidth}
\subfigure[$\pi^{RC}=25413$]{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
        \tikzset{dot/.style={circle,fill=#1,inner sep=0,minimum size=4pt}}
        \draw (1,2) node[dot=black]{}--(2,5)node[dot=black]{}--(3,4)node[dot=black]{}-- (4,1)node[dot=black]{}--(5,3)node[dot=black]{};
        \draw (1.5,3.5) node[xshift=-.3cm] {\small $X_4$};
        \draw(2.5,4.5) node[xshift=.2cm,yshift=.2cm] {\small $X_3$};
        \draw(3.5,2.5) node[xshift=-.2cm, yshift=-.1cm] {\small $X_2$};
        \draw(4.5,2) node[xshift=.3cm] {\small $X_1$};
    \end{tikzpicture}}



\caption{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Actually, what you've written is a bit wrong. The optional argument to the `subfigure` environment defined by `subcaption` is not the number of the figure (a,b,c, etc) but `t`, `c` or `b`, defining the vertical 'anchor' of the `subfigure`, similar to the `minipage` environment.